# Wpf TreeView Get Item from ContextMenu

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, treeview

Hi 
I got the following Treeview, with a ContextMenu with the following MenuItems DoSomeThingOnItem and DoAnotherThingOnItem.

But what do I need to do, for me to get the Item, where the contextmenuitem was clicked?

```
<TreeView Name="treeView1" ItemsSource="{Binding Regions}"  AllowDrop="True" PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="TreeView1PreviewMouseRightButtonDown">
            <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <!-- This Style binds a TreeViewItem to a TreeViewItemViewModel.-->
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True" />
                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <TreeView.Resources>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:ProductViewModel}"
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Width="16" Height="16" Margin=" 3,0" Source="Images\item.png"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                        <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu>
                                <MenuItem Header="DoSomeThingOnItem"></MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem Header="DoAnotherThingOnItem"></MenuItem>
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                    </StackPanel>

                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
```

Just to make it more clear, here is my contextmenu

```
 <ContextMenu>
   <MenuItem Header="DoSomeThingOnItem"></MenuItem>
   <MenuItem Header="DoAnotherThingOnItem"></MenuItem>
 </ContextMenu>
```

I have already tried with the Click event, but It just gives me a

```
MenuItem contextMenuItem = (MenuItem)sender;
```

And I can't figure out a way to get the item from that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See if this is related:

[Find Bound Item from TreeViewItem from ContextMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560796/find-bound-item-from-treeviewitem-from-contextmenu)

Comment: Thanks, that did it, and here is the code I use in my click event.

((CategoryViewModel)(sender as MenuItem).DataContext)